# Getting all input values with same class and replacing them with % symbol as a "Numbers"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting input values with the same class name and replacing the value along with % symbol and it shouldn't be a string or object the type should be "number".

Eg: if I enter 25 in the input field it should be changed to 25% and that 25% should be number, not a string.

Comment: Can you add more information? That's really not enough to go on.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: In JavaScript something cannot be both of type number and have a %-sign in it.

Comment: If I have added % symbol inside the input field by default but in the console, I'm reading it as a string. can I convert it to number?

Comment: Just apply `parseFloat` on it?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, tried it but didn't work @trincot

Comment: Well, I have used it in my answer below. Did you run the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is of `type="number"`, you can't have a non-numeric character (%) in its value. You could add a label to your input to display the percentage sign right after it, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/q95gnwcf/).

```
  <input style="width:40px" type="number" id="myNumericInput" name="myInput"/>
  <label for="myInput" style="font-weight: bold">%</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply `parseFloat` on the input's value, as that will stop parsing as soon as it encounters the %-sign. So the digits that precede it, get evaluated.

You already made that the %-sign is added. You may also want to remove it again, when the user comes back to that input, and starts editing again.

If you want, you could make a little jQuery plugin to make this addition/removal of the %-sign happen whenever the user focusses on the input or steps away from it.

Here is a live snippet: edit and tab away and back to the input-element to see what it does.

```js
// Define jQuery plugin:
$.fn.percentage = function () {
    function clean() {
        return this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    }
    this.each(function () {
        $(this).on("focus", clean)
               .on("blur", function () {
            if (clean.call(this)) this.value += "%"; 
        });
    });
}

// Demo
// 1. Automatically add/remove %:
$("input").percentage();

// 2. Illustrate the use of parseFloat
$("input").on("change", function () {
    console.log(parseFloat($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```